# Secure my php files in case the php module of apache doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, debian

The other day, something happened on my website(s) and it scared me, and showed me that I have a security flaw in my Apache virtual-host setup.

I use php7.0 from [DotDeb](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/). I was `sudo apt-get upgrade`ing my Debian Jessie, and for some reason, the php module of apache got disabled. I didn't notice that, but the consequence was that all my php files on my website became downloadable! This creates a security risk because, for example, my database passwords became visible for the visitors of my website.

What is the correct configuration that guarantees that such event won't happen? For example, how can I make apache fail if php is not present? Or any other solution that will not give my php files to my website visitors in such an event!

The following is my current virtual-host configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /web/root/directory
    ServerName www.example.com

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
    </IfModule>
    php_admin_flag engine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCompression off
    SSLCipherSuite AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH

   SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.chn
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Move your PHP files (with the possible exception of index.php) outside of the web root and its subfolders

Comment: @MarkBaker It's WordPress actually, I don't have that kind of freedom.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You do with the configuration file. See the [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) article in the Codex, under "Securing wp-config.php" -- you can move your wp-config one directory above your web root, so it's inaccessible to browsers. You'll also see tricks in there for htaccess configurations, which are independent of PHP, to help prevent other issues. (I'm voting to move this to ServerFault, as it's more server configuration than programming.)

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks for the link. I'll read it and do that as it sounds like a good idea. But I still would like to know if it's possible to get apache to stop if the php module isn't present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
<Directory />
    <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Snarky note: that's going to be painful as OP's on PHP7. :-p Otherwise, good additional step.

Comment: @ceejayoz Right you are. I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot! That does it! Though for a test, I did remove the "!" not operator to see whether it works, and apache threw an error on `configtest`: `AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/conf-available/theconf.conf:
deny not allowed here`. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist No. In what context is the added code? Also note that I edited my post to clarify that you need to use a `Directory` block.

Comment: Perhaps I got this error because I didn't put this in a `<Directory>` tag, but rather directly in the config of `virtualhost`. Nevertheless, it does the job! Throwing an error is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Well I guess it does the trick, albeit inadvertently.